# Codeception - can't use DB module, because of invalid configuration

Tags: sqlite, codeception

I've added DB module to acceptance suite.
And I've put:

```
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'sqlite:storage/database.sqlite'
            user:
            password:
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

in codeception.yml

Then i need to build:

cept build gives me:

```
  [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfig]
  Db module is not configured!
  Options: dsn, user, password are required
                  Please, update the configuration and set all the required fields
```

It's the same when I set user and password for dummy values.

I think sqlite doesn't need user and password - I can't get it work. I would appreciate any help, I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `user` and `password` to empty values `''` instead of nothing:

```
Db:
      dsn: 'sqlite:storage/database.sqlite'
      user: ''
      password: ''
      dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
modules:
    enabled: [Db]
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'sqlite:storage/database.sqlite'
            user:
            password:
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Db`** module requires **`user`** and **`password`**, these have filled